# Limit false in spite of LH limit and RH limit same

Tags: limits

So I have, [image]

I thought a limit exists if Left-hand limit and R-Hand limit is same, which is true in this case. But the answer sheet says this statement is false. Why is it?

Comment: Did you replace $x$ with $0$ in $1-\sin^2(x^2)$?

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false because the limit (which exists) is $1$, not $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, $\lim\limits_{x\to0}(1-x^2)=1$, which is true from both the left and right. Since $\sin(x^2)\to0$ in that limit, the limit would still be $1$.

We have that:

$$f(g(x))=1-\sin^2(x^2)$$

unless $x=0$, and since you are taking the limit as $x\to0$, all you need to do is plug in to see that the statement is wrong. Does this help?